# blueimp-gallery doesn't work when you change hash on website

Tags: javascript, hash, gallery

When I click on items in the menu, the hash on the url changes. Unfortunately, when the hash changes, blueimp-gallery stops working.

This is the page where the problem occurs - http://serwer211754.lh.pl.

I tried to solve this problem using the following code:

```
window.location.hash = ''

carousel_fullscreen_div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    blueimp.Gallery(gallery, {
        fullscreen: true
    })
})
```

but delete hash before start blueimp doesn't help.

Do you have any ideas to solve the problem?